# Problema de punteros a arreglos (diferencia entre *(p++) y *(p+i))

Tags: c++, array, punteros, struct

Tengo un problema, creo que usar esto `*(p++)` es muy diferente a esto `*(p+i)`.

```
    int arreglo1[5] = {3,6,1,2,7};
    int *p = arreglo1;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<*(p++)<<" ";

    }
    cout<<endl<<*p;
}
```

Me imprime un número 5, lo que significa que se encuentra en una dirección de memoria despúes.

Y ahora tengo esto:

```
    int arreglo1[5] = {3,6,1,2,7};
    int *p = arreglo1;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<*(p+i)<<" ";

    }
    cout<<endl<<*p;
}
```

Me imprime el número 3, lo que significa que se quedó en la primer posición

No entiendo muy bien esto, pero llego a la conclusión que `*(p++)` recorre uno por uno y `*(p+i)` es lo mismo que hacer `p[i]` (eso es lo que creo).

**Pero la incógnita que me hizo confundir es esto:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Alumno{//Creo una estructura llamada Alumno
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
    int promedio;
}alumnos[3],*p=alumnos;//Creo un arreglo y un puntero que apunta a la primera posición del puntero

int main(){

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){//En este bucle lleno los datos al arreglo
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del alumno: "; cin.getline(p->nombre,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Ingrese la edad: "; cin>>p->edad;
        cout<<"Ingrese el promedio de "<<p->nombre<<" : ";cin>>p->promedio;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<endl;
        p++;//Hago que el puntero avance
    }

    cout<<(p+1)->nombre;//AHORA QUE QUIERO IMPRIMIR UN ELEMENTO DEL ARREGLO, NO ME LO IMPRIME
    
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que me explicaron es que como hago recorrer mi arreglo `*(p++)` se queda en la posición `*(p+2)` y al usar  `*(p+1)` es como que estuviera sumando y me imprimiría `*(p+3)`

Pero pensé que esto `(*p+1)` era basicamente esto `p[1]`.

**Estoy confundido**

Comment: `p + x`  **devuelve un nuevo valor**, y `p` se queda como estaba. `p++` **altera** o cambia `p`. Te sugiero revisar de que operadores dispones en el lenguaje y como funcionan. Hay **muchos** tutoriales disponibles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no tienes muy claro el tema de los punteros.

Un puntero no es más que una variable que almacena direcciones de memoria, la definición parece que si está bien asentada. El problema es a la hora de usarlos.

Un puntero no es muy diferente al resto de variables del programa:

- Almacena un valor
- Tiene un ciclo de vida
- ...

A mi me da la impresión que esto no último no lo tienes tan claro.

En el ejemplo que dices que te confunde:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){//En este bucle lleno los datos al arreglo
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del alumno: "; cin.getline(p->nombre,20,'\n');
    cout<<"Ingrese la edad: "; cin>>p->edad;
    cout<<"Ingrese el promedio de "<<p->nombre<<" : ";cin>>p->promedio;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<endl;
    p++;//Hago que el puntero avance
}

cout<<(p+1)->nombre;//AHORA QUE QUIERO IMPRIMIR UN ELEMENTO DEL ARREGLO, NO ME LO IMPRIME
```

Creo entender que tu lo que esperas es que el puntero tenga un comportamiento dual:

- Dentro del bucle se modifica para poder recorrer la colección
- Fuera del bucle se restaura su valor original mágicamente

El segundo punto, lamentablemente, no va a suceder en C++.

Al usar el operador de incremento sobre una variable (sea o no puntero), su valor cambia de forma permanente:

```
int a = 0;
int *b = 0;

a++;
b++;

std::cout << a << ' ' << (void*)b;
```

Y esto es lo que está sucediendo en tu bucle. Incrementas el valor del puntero para recorrer la colección.

Lo que sucede al terminar el bucle es que el puntero se queda apuntando al final de la colección, por lo que ese puntero, en su estado actual, no te servirá para mucho.

Por verlo en perspectiva, inicialmente `p` apunta al inicio de una colección con 3 elementos:

```
ELEM0                    | ELEM1                    | ELEM2                    | XX ...
[nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] |
^
p
```

Dentro del bucle realizas tres incrementos sobre `p`, luego la dirección de memoria apuntada por `p` se verá modificada 3 veces:

Primer incremento

```
ELEM0                    | ELEM1                    | ELEM2                    | XX ...
[nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] |
                           ^
                           p
```

Segundo incremento

```
ELEM0                    | ELEM1                    | ELEM2                    | XX ...
[nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] |
                                                      ^
                                                      p
```

Tercer incremento

```
ELEM2                    | ELEM1                    | ELEM2                    | XX ...
[nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] |
                                                                                 ^
                                                                                 p
```

Tras esto, el programa intenta hacer `cout << (p+1)->nombre`, es decir, consultas el valor del campo `nombre` del siguiente elemento al apuntado por `p`, pero `p` ya está fuera del array.

Lo que sucede aquí es que el compilador sabe cuánto ocupa cada elemento de la lista (es por ello que *sabe* recorrer la colección de elementos). Así, si tu le pides pasar al siguiente elemento, el incrementa convenientemente el valor de `p` ... pero el compilador no va a comprobar si en algún momento te *sales* del array. Esa responsabilidad es tuya.

Así, volviendo al ejemplo, al hacer `p+1` el compilador calcula la dirección de memoria de un hipotético siguiente elemento:

```
ELEM2                    | XX ...
[nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] | [nombre][edad][promedio] 
                           ^                          ^
                           p                          p+1
```

Y, a partir de esa posición de memoria, calcula el *offset* en el que se debería encontrar el campo `nombre`... y esa dirección de memoria es la que le pasa a `cout`.

Dado que `p` no tiene ningún sitio donde guardar su *posición orignal*, para solventar este problema tenemos, básicamente, 2 soluciones de uso común:

1. Usar una copia del puntero. De esta forma modificas la copia, dejando el original intacto apuntando al inicio de la colección:

   ```
   Alumno* copia = p; // Copiamos el puntero
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){//En este bucle lleno los datos al arreglo
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del alumno: "; cin.getline(copia->nombre,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Ingrese la edad: "; cin>>copia->edad;
        cout<<"Ingrese el promedio de "<<p->nombre<<" : ";cin>>copia->promedio;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<endl;
        copia++;//Hago que el puntero avance
    }
   ```
2. No modificamos el puntero. En este caso usamos offsets. Un offset es un desplazamiento respecto a la posición dada por el puntero. El puntero no se modifica en ningún momento, luego apunta al inicio de la colección en todo momento

   ```
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){//En este bucle lleno los datos al arreglo
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del alumno: "; cin.getline(p[i].nombre,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Ingrese la edad: "; cin>>p[i].edad;
        cout<<"Ingrese el promedio de "<<p->nombre<<" : ";cin>>p[i].promedio;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<endl;
    }
   ```

   Nota que los offsets también se pueden aplicar usando aritmética de punteros

   ```
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){//En este bucle lleno los datos al arreglo
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del alumno: "; cin.getline((p+i)->nombre,20,'\n');
        cout<<"Ingrese la edad: "; cin>>(p+i)->edad;
        cout<<"Ingrese el promedio de "<<p->nombre<<" : ";cin>>(p+i)->promedio;
        fflush(stdin);
        cout<<endl;
    }
   ```

   Y aquí es donde vemos cómo `p++` **no es lo mismo** que `p+i`. Lo primero es un incremento que modifica `p`, mientras que `p+i` no. Fíjate que si `p+i` modificase `p`, sería imposible recorrer una colección. Imagínate el siguiente caso de uso:

   ```
    int array[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int*p = array;
    for( int i=0; i<5; i++ )
      std::cout << *(p+i);
   ```

   Si esto modificase `p` acabaríamos accediendo a los siguientes índices:

   ```
    i=0 => p -> array[0]                  -> 1
    i=1 => p -> array[0 + 1] = array[ 1]  -> 2
    i=2 => p -> array[1 + 2] = array[ 3]  -> 4
    i=3 => p -> array[3 + 3] = array[ 6]  -> ?? (fuera del array)
    i=4 => p -> array[6 + 4] = array[10]  -> ?? (fuera del array)
   ```

   Y, sin embargo, el comportamiento que se reproduce es el esperado, es decir, podemos ver como se imprimen todos los valores del arrray.

Y ya, para terminar, un par de detalles:

**No uses fflush con stdin**

`fflush` está pensado para ser usado con **dispositivos de salida**. Usar `fflush` con un dispositivo de entrada es un comportamiento indeterminado (funciona porque el compilador que usas ahora mismo te ofrece ese soporte, pero no es algo que vaya a pasar siempre)

**No mezcles I/O de C con la propia de C++**

`fflush` y `stdin` son mecanismos de I/O heredados de C, mientras que `cout` es propio de C++.

Mezclar ambos mundos puede ser peligroso. Por ejemplo, hay una función que no te suelen explicar en clase que es [`sync_with_stdio`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio), que básicamente permite elegir si queremos sincronizar la I/0 de C y la de C++.

Si alguna vez has intentado resolver algún reto de programación, habrás notado que la entrada/salida de C++ es muy lenta. Y es algo que llama la anteción, ya que la lógica nos dicta que debería ser más rápida que la de C:

```
int a;
std::cin >> a;   // Convertir a int
scanf("%d", &a); // Interpretar "%d" y convertir a int
```

Esta latencia se debe a que por defecto, por compatibilidad y esas cosas, ambas entradas/salidas están sincronizadas. Si se desactiva la sincronización vemos como la lógica se impone y la I/O de C++ deja de ser tan lenta y pesada.

Otro efecto de desincronizar la entrada/salida es que si tu código mezcla C con C++ puedes obtener comportamientos indeterminados, ya que cada entrada/salida manejará sus propios datos... es decir, un valor introducido por el usuario acabará en la I/O de C, en la de C++, o parte en una y parte en otra

Dicho todo esto, para limpiar el buffer de entrada desde C++:

```
std::cin.clear(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
```

Esta línea, básicamente, descarta todo lo que se encuentre en el buffer de entrada hasta el primer salto de línea, que también se descarta.

`std::numeric_limits` es una plantilla de C++ que proporciona información sobre los tipos básicos de C++. Así `std::numeric_limits<int>` proporciona información sobre el tipo `int`. El método estático `max()` devuelve el valor más alto que se puede almacenar en dicho tipo.

**No uses variables globales**

Dado que se puede acceder a ellas desde cualquier punto del programa es complicado controlar cuándo cambia su valor. Los errores relacionados con las variables globales son más complicados de corregir